# Unable to uninstall typora

Tags: windows, uninstall

Today I was trying to use Typora, it popped up a windows saying *the beta version of typora is expired, please download and install a new version.*

I think I need to uninstall it, but when I opened my geek uninstaller, I couldn't find its name. I opened Programs and Features in Control Panel, and couldn't find Typora's entry as well. I am pretty sure I could find its entry when the beta version wasn't expired. And it is not uninstalled I'm pretty sure.

PS: My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to do what it said: download and install a new version?

Comment: @gronostaj the new version is a paid version

Comment: [This is the second result a search engine gave me for the term "typora uninstall"](https://github.com/typora/typora-issues/issues/4700)

Comment: If you still cannot find it, navigate to its installation location and run the "uninstall.exe" or similar